# Separate data in two groups

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
  17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22)
y1 = c(1, 6, 2, 5, 4, 7, 9, 6, 8, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 5, 8, 9, 
  5, 4, 7)

plot(x1, y1)
fit <- lm(y1 ~ x1)
fit
abline(fit, col = "black")

prediction <- predict(fit)`
```

I want to separate the data in two groups using the next condition:

```
    if (y1 < prediction) {print("Negative number")} 
    else if (y1 > prediction) {print("Positive number")}
```

But it appears: Warning messages:

```
1: In if (y1 < prediction) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (y1 > prediction) { :
    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: `ifelse( y1 < prediction, "Negative number", "Positive number")`. Output will appear on console when execute. Use `cat` if scripting or from inside a function. `if` is not vectorised, but `ifelse` is. This is probably the most frequently asked question by new R-users coming from SAS or SPSS.

Comment: Could you please remove the rstudio tag. R and rstudio are separate pieces of software. Your question has nothing to do with rstudio.

Comment: The last statement prediction<-predict(fit) is not needed.  The result of the lm expression all ready contains the fitted values.  fit$fitted is equivalent to predict(fit).